# Assert that vector is partitioned by value x

Tags: c++, vector

The code snippet

```
std::vector<int> v{ 3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 6};
Partition(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin());
```

Should rearrange the vector v such that the first n elements are smaller than or equal to 3 and the following elements are larger than 3. The resulting vector should look like this:

> 1,2,3,5,8,4,7,6

How can I test if Partition produces the correct results in an assert statement that verbally asserts the following:

> Assert that the first part of the vector only contains elements that
>   are
>       smaller than or equal to x and that the seconds part contains only elements 
>       that are greater than x

?

Comment: You need to write a checker function that returns bool, and place it into the assert: `assert(CheckTheVector(v))`

Comment: With a loop over all the elements and the correct if expression

Comment: If a slight bend of the requirements is tolerable, then look at `std::nth_element`

Comment: Does your Partition function return the position of the pivot like [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)?

Comment: see: [std::is_partitioned](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_partitioned).

Comment: You have written your result as '{12,3,...}'.  Would '{3,1,2,....}' be an acceptable result too?

Comment: Is using "Partitions" part of the requirement? If I read the title of the question carefully, I see that it asks for a boolean statement about a given vector (v) that is controlled by two arguments (`n` and `x`). I do not see any effort be you to turn this description into code... So, maybe your title is absolutely misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the awesome folks at the committee, your requirement for the vector to be partitioned can be expressed as "is the vector partitioned?", which maps quite well to the standard [`std::is_partitioned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_partitioned) algorithm. Isn't life beautiful?

```
assert(std::is_partitioned(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int e) { return e <= 3; }));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thats exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

The assertion you want to check may be reformulated as "the rightmost element which is strictly greater than `3` is before the leftmost element which is less or equal than `3`".

So, you can find positions of these two elements (see [std::find_if documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/), it may be used for both ordinary and reverse-iterators), and then compare them in the `assert` statement. The check will work in linear time and require constant memory.

Answer (score 2):

> Assert the first n elements of a vector are smaller than a value x
>
> ```
> 1,2,3,5,8,4,7,6
> ```

The initial partition of your result appears to be sorted. If that is guaranteed, then the simplest test is:

```
v[n - 1] <= x
```

If the sorting isn't guaranteed, then you can use `std::all_of` to test each of the first `n` elements separately.

---

> Assert that the first part of the vector only contains elements that are smaller than or equal to x and that the seconds part contains only elements that are greater than x

This describes a partitioned sequence. This can be tested with `std::is_partitioned`.

Comment: The sequence `5,8,4,7,6` is not sorted.

Comment: The OP does not know `n`, and want to check in assertion that such `n` exists.

Comment: @Nobody I intended to mean that the first partition appears to be sorted. The sorting of latter partition doesn't matter.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Well, absent any other definition I'd say the usual integer order is intended. user2079303 I see, but I would not expect Partition to guarantee sorting. Anyways you'd also have to test the second part for any elements that are not larger than `x` to get the correct test algorithm.

Comment: @Nobody Yeah, it appears that the question in the body is a bit more complicated than the question in the title.

Comment: @user2079303 I don't think you can assume the initial sequence will necessarily be sorted.

Comment: @MartinBonner Then you have to test all of the first `n` elements.

Comment: Given that the whole purpose of the question is to determine if the vector is correct, I don't see how you can avoid testing *all* elements.  (First n to make sure they are less-equal or less-equal-and-sorted, remainder to check they are greater-than.)

Comment: @MartinBonner The question in the title doesn't require testing all elements `Assert the first n elements of a vector are smaller than a value x`. The question in the body does.